# Unable to hide nav-tabs if its tab content is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, navbar

I am using bootstrap nav-tabs where if the tab content is empty,I don't want to show the tab.

I have a <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/47zkydd3/1/)</kbd>,where it hides the tab. I've written that one for particular tab(using an `id`).

The problem is if I've more tabs,So I've implemented using a class.But I am unable to get the result.

<kbd>[**Demo of My problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/2vpybjs6/1/)</kbd>

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" class="EmptyFind">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" class="EmptyFind"></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" class="EmptyFind">Message</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" class="EmptyFind">Settings</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".EmptyFind").each(function() {
    var $tid = $(this).attr("id");
    var $txt = $(this).text();
    var $tohide = $("#myTab").find($('a[data-target=#+'$tid ']'));
    if ($txt == "") {
      $('a[data-target=#+'$tid']').closest('li').hide();
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: You have added two class atrribute so make it one.

Comment: @harry Very bigggg error.Too much coding..Thanks for getting me caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added two class atrribute so make it one

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
          <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active EmptyFind" id="home">Home</div>
          <div class="tab-pane EmptyFind" id="profile" ></div>
          <div class="tab-pane EmptyFind" id="messages" >Message</div>
          <div class="tab-pane EmptyFind" id="settings">Settings</div>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                      $(".EmptyFind").each(function() {
                        var $tid = $(this).attr("id");
                        var $txt = $(this).text();
                        if ($txt == "") {                               
                          $('a[data-target=#'+$tid+']').closest('li').hide();
                        }
                      });

                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".EmptyFind").each(function() {
    var tid = $(this).attr("id");
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (txt == "") {
      $("a[data-target=" + tid + "]").parent().hide();
    }
  });

})
</script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active EmptyFind" id="home">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane EmptyFind" id="profile"></div>
  <div class="tab-pane EmptyFind" id="messages">Message</div>
  <div class="tab-pane EmptyFind" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

You had this errors:

- You define class attribute twice on the tabs.
- You selector to get the
  item to hide was incorrect due to the # sign and string concatenation
  ends with syntax error.